# Getting a linux SDL2 program to run on a computer that does not have SDL2 installed?

Tags: c++, sdl

I recently developed a small SDL2 game. The game ran fine on my computer because I have SDL, SDL_image, SDL_mixer, and SDL_ttf installed. However, everyone who downloaded the game did not have SDL2 and the extensions installed, so they could not run the application. How can I make the application usable even for people who don't have SDL2 installed?

Comment: How are you distributing the game?

Comment: I put the game up on gamejolt. It is basically the executable and the resources folder into an archive. http://gamejolt.com/games/point/98529

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could statically link you libs, that way no need to have SDL installed.

A way to do it :

```
g++ -o program [sources.cpp] -Wl,-Bstatic -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image \
-lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf -Wl,-Bdynamic [dynamically linked libs]
```

Note : If you use SDL2, you must use the SDL2 builds of peripheral libs otherwise you risk all kinds of errors.

Comment: I doubt DLL files are going to solve anything on Linux ;)

Comment: Static linking is a correct solution, do be aware of the [legal conditions](https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQLicensing) though : you can link the SDL statically only if you offer a way for the user to relink it with another version.

Comment: You are right for earlier versions of SDL. But SDL2 is under the zlib license and therefore restriction free.

Comment: And SDL2 now has a [internal dynamic linking...thing](https://plus.google.com/+RyanGordon/posts/TB8UfnDYu4U) so that even a statically-linked version of SDL2 can be upgraded.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `-rpath` option to ld to specify search directories for dynamic libraries.

Using `-rpath .` (`-Wl,-rpath .` to pass it from GCC) will enable loading the libraries from the executable's directory. Just put the appropriate `.so` files there and they will be found.